# AsyncTask Error on JSONobject response and string conversion

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

Building a simple registration process for android. Have backend api for this process. Data as JSON is storing in DB and getting response. I want to get this response as a string from main method and according to this i wrote code. But i think that am made a mistake on asynctask. As a novice i don't get this, probably my calling is not in the right time but can't organize it. So need suggestion.

**JsonPostClient.java**

```
public class JsonPostClient {

  private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";

  public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjSend.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpPostRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response
                    .getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null
                    && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString = convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.e("ERROR IS", resultString);
            instream.close();

            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

My registration page.
**RegisterActivity.java**

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

String responseResult;

JsonPostClient postData = new JsonPostClient();

private EditText etName, etPassword, etEmail, etPhone, etAddress;
private Button btnReg;

RegInfo person;
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set View to register.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_phone);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_address);
    btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    // using getter setter class
    person = new RegInfo();
    person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
    person.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString());
    person.setPassword(etPassword.getText().toString());
    person.setPhone(etPhone.getText().toString());
    person.setAddress(etAddress.getText().toString());

    // Listening to Login Screen link
    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });

    // Register button onclick
    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            else {

                new HttpAsyncTask().execute();
            }

        }
    });
}

public String PostData(RegInfo person) {

    String URL = "http://192.168.1.149/500apps/index.php?r=locShareReg/post";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {

        jsonObject.put("user_name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.put("password", person.getPassword());
        jsonObject.put("email", person.getEmail());
        jsonObject.put("phone", person.getPhone());
        jsonObject.put("address", person.getAddress());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject responseReceive = new JSONObject();
    responseReceive = JsonPostClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObject);

    responseResult = responseReceive.optString("Success");

    Log.i("responseResult", responseResult);

    return responseResult;

}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        person = new RegInfo();
        person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
        person.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString());
        person.setPassword(etPassword.getText().toString());
        person.setPhone(etPhone.getText().toString());
        person.setAddress(etAddress.getText().toString());

        return PostData(person);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        Log.d("response onpost", result);

    }
}

private boolean validate() {
    if (etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if (etEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if (etPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if (etPhone.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if (etAddress.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

 }
```

//My posted **JSONdata**

```
  {
    "user_name": "Ashif",
    "phone": "52527282",
    "address": "Gulshan",
    "email": "demo@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
   }
```

i can see it in logcat

//response

```
 "Success"
```

This response is showen from JsonPostClient.java but i want to print it from RegisterActivity class. So i did this

```
    JSONObject responseReceive = new JSONObject();
    responseReceive = JsonPostClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObject);

    responseResult = responseReceive.optString("Success");

    Log.i("responseResult", responseResult);
```

But Always Shows Error

```
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): at  android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at com.example.shareapplogregcheck.RegisterActivity.PostData(RegisterActivity.java:132)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at com.example.shareapplogregcheck.RegisterActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:151)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at com.example.shareapplogregcheck.RegisterActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   08-27 12:00:56.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: what is on  line 132

Comment: Are you sure your AsyncTask has finished when you want to print the output? Usually an AsyncTask is not the best choice when you need something to be finished at a certain moment....

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin line 132 - responseResult = responseReceive.optString("Success");

Comment: @mylenereiners i also doubt that. but need to organize

Comment: your `JsonPostClient.SendHttpPost()` is returning null, my best bet would be `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity()` is null for some reason.

Comment: But you can also check ^^ yourself with some log statements. You have a stacktrace to know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1:**

You need to change `doInBackground` of `HttpAsyncTask` with `Void` parameter if you don't want to take any `parameter` in AsyncTask.

Code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

   ...
}
```

Your error log line:

> at com.example.shareapplogregcheck.RegisterActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)